# How to get bjobs finished before CLEAN_PERIOD

Tags: linux

I know *bjobs -d* will show recently finished jobs with in CLEAN_PERIOD,
but I want to know bjobs submitted before that CLEAN_PERIOD. Is there any way?

-d
    Displays information about jobs that finished recently, within an interval specified by CLEAN_PERIOD in lsb.params (the default period is 1 hour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bjobs man page](http://delphiwww.cern.ch/offline/computing/bjobs.html) suggests using **bhist**:

> To display finished jobs, option **-d** or **-a** must be used when *jobId* is
>   not specified. Note that only the jobs that have finished within the
>   last **CLEAN_PERIOD** seconds can be displayed (see **lsb.params**(5)).  For
>   jobs finished more than **CLEAN_PERIOD** seconds ago, the **bhist** command
>   can be used to display their information.